# Where can I watch Koe no Katachi?

Tags: resources, koe-no-katachi

Koe no Katachi has already been released but I can't find it anywhere. I only found the trailer. Where can I watch it legally?

Comment: Some advice: people here get touchy sometimes if you ask where you can watch something and don't make it clear you want to watch it legally. We don't allow questions asking for fansubs or torrents, and if you aren't clear, your question could end up closed. I went ahead and edited it in for you this time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [official page](http://koenokatachi-movie.com/bddvd/) for the movie, Koe no Katachi will have a home video release on May 17th, 2017.

You will most likely be able to find it available in iTunes and other retailers after this release date.

Comment: While that is *the* official source, I'm not convinced that this source lists distribution in the OP's language (which I would presume English).

Comment: @Makoto There isn't news for an official English language release, and they weren't very specific in their question. Fansubbers will likely produce downloadable subtitles which he can use with the legal video source shortly after the movie is released.

Comment: There is going to be an official English language release in some regions. It will be screened in Australian and New Zealand cinemas in April. I doubt there will be a similar US release, but at the very least it means that a (probably subtitled) version will exist.